# wrong result with s command in perl

Tags: perl

Hi i want to find & replace some content of string

```
$source_folder = "D:\workdir\Devunit\11.1\latest";
$desitnation_folder = "D:\workdir\Devunit\10.1.3_Super\latest_Super";
$src_file = D:\workdir\Devunit\11.1\latest\src\tcbom\userver\buslogic\framework\bomitemfactory.cpp;    

$dest_file = $src_file;
print " $dest_file \n";
$dest_file =~ s/$source_folder/$desitnation_folder/;
print " $dest_file \n";
```

both print results shows

```
D:\workdir\Devunit\11.1\latest\src\tcbom\userver\buslogic\framework\bomitemfactory.cpp
```

plz let me know where I am wrong

Comment: `use strict;`! `use warnings;`! Look at the values of your strings! ``\`` is an escape character!

Comment: `desitnation` is a typo waiting to happen. Or already did, depending on your point of view. `use strict` will not help you spell correctly, but it will help you spell consistently.

Comment: Also, in your code, the string for `$src_file` is not quoted at all. That code would not compile, and the fact that you are posting it here gives a rather careless impression. It is difficult for us to correct your code if you don't post the code you are using.

Comment: Being Windows, you can also use forward slash `/` for your paths.

Answer (score 3):

Use `quotemeta` if you don't want anything in your strings to be special, i.e. to have those interpreted literally.  The following should work for you:

```
$source_folder = q(D:\workdir\Devunit\11.1\latest);
$desitnation_folder = q(D:\workdir\Devunit\10.1.3_Super\latest_Super);
$src_file = q(D:\workdir\Devunit\11.1\latest\src\tcbom\userver\buslogic\framework\bomitemfactory.cpp);

$dest_file = $src_file;
print " $dest_file \n";
$dest_file =~ s/\Q$source_folder\E/$desitnation_folder/;
print " $dest_file \n";
```

---

You might also want to refer to [How do I match a regular expression that's in a variable?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-match-a-regular-expression-thats-in-a-variable-)

Comment: I would use `q` here, not `qw`, especially since Windows pathnames often contain spaces.

Comment: It is really to bad that the highlighter doesn't handle `q//` correctly.